# will dc converter discharge battary?

Tags: arduino, batteries, dc, dc-dc-converter

I am using a mini-360 dc-dc converter with arduino pro mini, so will mini-360 discharge battery without any load? Is it correct to use power switch as on image?

[image: power switch]

Comment: This is unanswerable without the *implementation detail* or *specifications* of the converter, but the most likely answer is "yes" with how "how much" depending on those details.  Putting the switch upstream would be best.  Consider that your chosen battery is probably not the best choice to begin with.

Comment: To be clear about your battery choice, what Chris is pointing out is that if you need 6-9V, traditional 9V batteries are one of the worst ways to obtain it.  Using a Li-ion 9V(same shape as the 9V you're using, but has li-ion and a voltage converter/battery protection board inside.  Charge via usb.) isn't a horrible idea if you really like that form factor.  9V batteries are expensive, don't store much power, have high internal resistance and should really only be used for specific tasks with very small loads.

Answer (score 0):

The mini 360 uses a [MP2307](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Monolithic-Power-Systems-MPS/MP2307DN-LF?qs=rC7bBWoQAAlAqAemW35Sxg%3D%3D) (as far as I can tell, some of them use a different converter).

It looks like the chip is always enabled and not in sleep mode, so the converter itself is always drawing a few mA. This will draw down the battery even when there is no load.

[image]

It would be wise to put the switch on the battery side so no current is wasted and the mini 360 is fully off.